# Differentiating the Ideal Gas Equation

Tags: derivatives, physics

I am working on differentiating the ideal gas equation PV = nrT with respect to time.

In the question I have to solve n is a constant.

Specifically, trying to find the change in pressure: P = (nRT)/V

I am getting myself confused because when I initially tried to solve this problem I took n and R out of the equation to give P' = nR [T' / V'], and then differentiated it using the quotient rule.

However, I have since realized that keeping the constants in the equation and differentiating them both to 1 gives different result to taking them outside the derivative equation and multiplying by the non-differentiated n and R. I am unsure on what basis you would take them out of the original equation in the first place (although I have seen this done with mathematical differentiation???]

Any advice would great.

Comment: Sorry to update this, in my given question, n is a constant.

Comment: You say you want to find the rate of change of pressure, but compared to what? A rate is a ratio, a comparison. So what's your other variable?

Comment: Time, sorry. Thought it was implied.

Comment: I guess it's very much not implied.

Comment: A general formula with respect to t, which is in fact not specified in the question.

Comment: Are the other variables also dependent on time?

Comment: the question is to find dP/dt, the time itself is not specified.

Comment: But your derivative computation is incorrect. You need to use the quotient rule to differentiate  $T/V$ (both of which are functions of $t$). Or what are your $P'$, $T'$, $V'$ supposed to mean here?

Comment: @TedShifrin I did state in my original question that I then used the quotient rule.

Comment: I asked you what the point of the $P'$, $T'$, $V'$ was. I would ordinarily use that notation to denote the time derivative.

Comment: @TedShifrin Sorry I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

Well, differentiating the equation gives $\mathrm d (PV)=\mathrm d(kT),$ or $$P\mathrm dV+V\mathrm dP=k\mathrm dT.$$ Then we have that $$P\frac{\mathrm dV}{\mathrm dt}+V\frac{\mathrm dP}{\mathrm dt}=k\frac{\mathrm dT}{\mathrm dt}.$$

Comment: Thank You. What is hte reason for combining n and R into k? Why can't you just keep it as n R. I take from your answer that you do not take the constants out of the equation, that would make it wrong yeah?

Comment: Also, I guess I don't really understand the use of partial derivatives and how this is different from simply using the chain rule or product rule or quotient rule. Just struggling to understand how one process (partial derivatives) relates to the other (derivative rules)?

Comment: @MEcho I did that because it doesn't matter. Or isn't $nR$ supposed to be constant?

Comment: @MEcho Yes, it's just the product rule. There's not much more to it than that.

Comment: But essentially the derivative of k is 1. So k becomes 1, yes?

Comment: @MEcho No. If you differentiate a constant multiple of some function, the result is the same constant multiple of the function's derivative. That is, for any constant $c$ and differentiable function $f,$ we have that $$\mathrm d(cf)=c\mathrm df.$$

Comment: @MEcho No! The derivative of a constant is $0$, not $1$.

Comment: Okay wait, but if a constant is expressed algebraically, as in n moles and R (ideal gas constant) is the derivative still 0, or 1? I understand that the derivative of a real number is 0.

Comment: @MEcho The derivative of a constant is $0.$ But none of the terms in your equation is constant. What you have is a product of a constant and a *variable,* and that can never have a difference of $0$ since it's actually changing!

Comment: Okay thanks!!!! That is why k still remains in the equation! Great I understand it now.